# Build failing after upgrading researchgate to 3.0.0

Tags: gradle, build, release, gradle-plugin, gradle-release-plugin

**Cannot set the value of extension 'release' property 'pushReleaseVersionBranch' of type java.lang.String using an instance of type java.lang.Boolean.**

it was working earlier with the same config for 'pushReleaseVersionBranch' as false
tried with removing that configuration, then I see the other issue.

**Cannot set the property 'requireBranch' because the backing field is final.**

not sure what is changed in the latest version.
how to fix this issue?

Comment: have you looked at their release notes?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this issue by using:

```
release {
    git {
        requireBranch.set('main')
    }
}
```